# I am trying to setup youbot and receive the below error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package pr2_msgs.

Set pr2_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
pr2_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

```
pr2_msgsConfig.cmake
pr2_msgs-config.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
youbot_driver_ros_interface/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193146/i-am-trying-to-setup-youbot-and-receive-the-below-error/) by [seggs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20257/seggs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The youbot_driver_ros_interface package depends on other packages. Probably you don't have the pr2_msgs package installed. You can install it with sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-msgs (use your ROS distro instead of hydro, if you are not using hydro).

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seggs](https://answers.ros.org/users/20257/seggs/) on 2014-09-22**:
Thanks man..it worked